# How to read multiple files and then manipulate them outside of the .onload loop using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I'm trying to read multiple files with FileReader() and then manipulate them, but I can't figure out how to use the file data outside of the onload loop. In this case, I can write to the writer div but only "unidentified" is output to the writer2 div. From what I've read, the problem likely has something to do with closure? I'm not sure.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Slurper(that)
{
  if(that.files)
  {
    var allMaps=new Array();
    for(i=0;i<that.files.length;i++)
      {

        var data = new FileReader()
        data.readAsText(that.files[i]);
        data.onload = function (event) 
        {
          var input=event.target.result;
          input=input.replace(/,/g," ");
          input=input.replace(/\u0009/g," ");
          input=input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g," ");
          input=input.replace(/  /g," ");
          input=input.replace(/ /g," ");
          allMaps[i]=input.split(" ");
          allMaps[i].splice(0,19);

          document.getElementById("writer").innerHTML+="<br>"+allMaps[i];   
        }
        document.getElementById("writer2").innerHTML+="<br>"+allMaps[i];
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you have here is a problem with synchronous vs asynchronous. The code to write to `writer2` runs BEFORE the files are loaded and the code to write to `writer` is run.

Answer (score 0):

ah - right. The problem is that your onload function is using `i` which is defined in the outer scope. So `i` will keep incrementing, and by the time your onload function calls `i` will be the number of files you pass in. I think what you might want is:

```
data.onload = function(index)
  return (event) 
        {
          var input=event.target.result;
          input=input.replace(/,/g," ");
          input=input.replace(/\u0009/g," ");
          input=input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g," ");
          input=input.replace(/  /g," ");
          input=input.replace(/ /g," ");
          allMaps[index]=input.split(" ");
          allMaps[index].splice(0,19);

          document.getElementById("writer").innerHTML+="<br>"+allMaps[index];   
        }
  }(i)
```

This will bind the current value of `i` to you callback function. Short answer is, yes, you should read up on closures and scopes.

Comment: That's one problem he has, but it's not the only problem. Filereaders are asynchronous.

Comment: Indeed - tbh I'm not really sure I understand what OP is trying to do. The way it is written I'm not sure much of anything will be written to `writer2`